# Interacting with X applications programmatically

Tags: x11, gtk, macro

I have an application which is built using GTK+. The application has a very simple interface. When started, the same window always opens, with a few input controls.

We want to write a script to fill in text in a couple fields, check a check box, then click a button. Pretty simple, and would be easy to do if a command-line version of the app were available (but it isn't).

What's the best way to approach interacting with an X application programmatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give xdotool ([Ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xdotool.1.html)) a look.

It's extremely powerful and should be able to do whatever you need.

http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Comment: i think the use of `xdotool` should only be considered in real emergency cases! Scripting something serious with `xdotool` is more a pain than a pleasure. Before you try `xdotool` ask the developer if the application has a `dbus` interface. That would make your plan much simpler.

Comment: @user1146332 I am using `xdotool` for various tasks without problem. I don't know what exactly *more a pain than a pleasure* is based on.

Comment: I'm using xdotool in a similar situation, and one thing that is a pain is that it can't look at the window to which it is sending events. One issue is nondeterministic timing: If the X program needs some time to process one event and would ignore the next event when it came too early, you need to add generous sleep pauses, but you never know how long is long enough.

Answer (score 3):

`xte`, part of [xautomation](http://hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html) is another tool that you can use to generates fake X11 input using the XTest extension.

From the homepage:

> Control X from the command line for scripts, and do "visual scraping" to find things on the screen. The control interface allows mouse movement, clicking, button up/down, key up/down, etc, and uses the XTest extension so you don't have the annoying problems that xse has when apps ignore sent events. The visgrep program find images inside of images and reports the coordinates, allowing progams to find buttons, etc, on the screen to click on.

Answer (score 0):

Xte works but it is really old. xdotool is at least in active development.

I did a lot of study of generating X Windows events, nominally to develop a keyboard macro program that can type strings, or the clipboard in applications that normally do not allow you to use paste.

X Window Event Handling Notes...
https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/X/event_handling.txt

Keyboard Macro (using xte or xdotool
https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/#keyboard_macro

Comment: good info in the links , why did someone downvoted this answer? +1
but it will be better to include the summary of apps found in the beginning of the article at less.